# Debian wifi drops out and then won't reconnect until reboot

Tags: debian, wifi

I am using Debian on a 2014 Macbook pro. I installed the broadcom wireless drivers from the [official debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/wl).

Every now and again I get this error where my laptop disconnects from the wifi and then won't reconnect.

Here's my dmesg log

```
blubee@naibed:~$ sudo dmesg | tail -300
[    4.861503] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
[    4.866024] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    4.868148] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    4.874956] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    4.895926] systemd-udevd[210]: starting version 215
[    4.943144] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    4.943229] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(GFX0) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    4.943253] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: yes  post: no)
[    4.944675] acpi device:02: registered as cooling_device5
[    4.951876] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    4.952396] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input1
[    4.956443] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    4.956517] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2
[    4.956519] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    4.957279] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input3
[    4.957281] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    4.957323] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input4
[    4.957324] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    4.966752] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=0262
[    4.966754] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.966755] usb 1-12: Product: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
[    4.966756] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[    4.981934] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X
[    4.983573] apple_gmux: Found gmux version 4.0.8 [indexed]
[    4.986832] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    4.988826] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input5
[    5.036285] Adding 130044k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:130044k SSFS
[    5.050995] EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    5.078064] systemd-journald[207]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    5.084564] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    5.097185] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    5.099368] ACPI: AC Adapter [ADP1] (on-line)
[    5.102243] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8406
[    5.102244] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[    5.102245] usb 2-4: Product: Card Reader
[    5.102246] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Apple
[    5.102246] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 000000000820
[    5.161695] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    5.180289] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    5.232325] input: bcm5974 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.2/input/input6
[    5.234530] usbcore: registered new interface driver bcm5974
[    5.273389] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    5.294383] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x000000000000efa0-0x000000000000efbf conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000efa0-0x000000000000efaf (\_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI) (20140424/utaddress-258)
[    5.296400] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0101
[    5.296401] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    5.296402] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
[    5.296858] hub 1-1.1:1.0: USB hub found
[    5.296875] hub 1-1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    5.304908] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[    5.304908] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    5.311849] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    5.322299] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    5.322332] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    5.322510] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
[    5.322593] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.322653] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    5.322657] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[    5.334642] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    5.337158] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    5.339366] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    5.341558] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    5.344447] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    5.347792] scsi1 : usb-storage 2-4:1.0
[    5.351332] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    5.357233] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    5.360824] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    5.361049] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    5.368478] iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
[    5.371291] input: Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/0003:05AC:0262.0001/input/input7
[    5.372333] wl0: online cpus 1
[    5.372380] usb 1-8.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    5.372637] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
[    5.373239] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    5.373240] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    5.373240] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    5.373241] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.373242] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.373243] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.373244] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.373246] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    5.373247] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    5.373247] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.373248] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    5.381161] alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
[    5.406833] pstore: Registered efi as persistent store backend
[    5.409213] apple 0003:05AC:0262.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input0
[    5.411971] alg: No test for crc32 (crc32-pclmul)
[    5.412213] sound hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig: line_outs=2 (0x12/0x13/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.412215] sound hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.412216] sound hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x10/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.412216] sound hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.412217] sound hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x21/0x0
[    5.412218] sound hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    5.412219] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x1c
[    5.412220] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x18
[    5.413303] applesmc: key=661 fan=2 temp=41 index=40 acc=0 lux=2 kbd=1
[    5.414887] apple 0003:05AC:0262.0002: hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input1
[    5.425545] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[    5.425607] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
[    5.425785] input: HDA Intel PCH SPDIF as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[    5.442590] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
[    5.442619] iTCO_wdt: unable to reset NO_REBOOT flag, device disabled by hardware/BIOS
[    5.443663] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    5.452797] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    5.455121] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    5.455495] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20130102 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    5.455499] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.65  Tue Dec  2 09:50:34 PST 2014
[    5.461571] usb 1-8.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=820a
[    5.461572] usb 1-8.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    5.461691] usb 1-8.1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    5.466188] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    5.479489] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
[    5.532183] usb 1-8.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    5.621360] usb 1-8.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=820b
[    5.621361] usb 1-8.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    5.621496] usb 1-8.2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    5.692039] usb 1-8.3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[    5.783424] usb 1-8.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8289
[    5.783425] usb 1-8.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.783428] usb 1-8.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    5.783429] usb 1-8.3: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[    5.784763] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
[    5.784897] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
[    5.785052] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input13
[    5.855994] usb 1-1.1.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[    5.942284] input: HID 05ac:820a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.1/1-8.1:1.0/0003:05AC:820A.0003/input/input14
[    5.942417] hid-generic 0003:05AC:820A.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [HID 05ac:820a] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8.1/input0
[    5.942547] input: HID 05ac:820b as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.2/1-8.2:1.0/0003:05AC:820B.0004/input/input15
[    5.942681] hid-generic 0003:05AC:820B.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [HID 05ac:820b] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8.2/input0
[    5.946730] usb 1-1.1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[    5.946771] usb 1-1.1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.946805] usb 1-1.1.1: Product: USB Receiver
[    5.946825] usb 1-1.1.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    5.984374] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0007: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1.1/input2
[    6.017575] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.020566] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[    6.020585] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[    6.020594] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[    6.020605] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[    6.020616] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[    6.020627] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[    6.020638] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[    6.020650] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.P0P2.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[    6.042465] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4041 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.1/1-1.1.1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0007/0003:046D:C52B.0008/input/input16
[    6.042567] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0008: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4041] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.1.1:1
[    6.349309] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     APPLE    SD Card Reader   3.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    6.349466] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    6.350433] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    6.963795] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    6.963808] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    6.963809] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.963814] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.963816] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.963824] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.966823] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    7.003865] usb 1-8.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[    7.031585] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.031588] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.031594] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.259362] usb 1-8.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[   11.030361] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[ 1038.623383] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[ 1038.623392] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[ 1038.623862] apple 0005:05AC:0255.0009: unknown main item tag 0x0
[ 1038.623968] input: Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.3/1-8.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/0005:05AC:0255.0009/input/input17
[ 1038.624088] apple 0005:05AC:0255.0009: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v0.50 Keyboard [ Keyboard] on 3c:15:c2:d1:3e:45
[ 6616.800822] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 6616.803887] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 6616.803892] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 6616.803893] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 6616.803896] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 6616.803899] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 6616.803900] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 6616.803903] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 6616.803905] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 6616.803907] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 6616.803909] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 6616.803911] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[ 6622.999652] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[11015.360076] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: IRQ timing workaround is activated for card #0. Suggest a bigger bdl_pos_adj.
[12269.080476] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: Unstable LPIB (64996 >= 32768); disabling LPIB delay counting
[14295.017760] perf interrupt took too long (2562 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[32174.689067] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[32174.693320] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[32174.693327] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[32174.693329] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[32174.693333] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[32174.693335] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[32174.693337] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[32174.693340] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[32174.693343] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[32174.693346] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[32174.693348] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[32174.693350] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[32180.840742] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[39016.816854] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[39016.825530] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[39016.825539] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[39016.825542] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[39016.825548] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39016.825552] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39016.825557] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39016.825562] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39016.825567] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[39016.825572] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[39016.825577] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39016.825581] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[39022.948704] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[39623.325512] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[39623.327655] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[39623.327659] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[39623.327660] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[39623.327662] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39623.327664] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39623.327665] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39623.327667] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39623.327669] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[39623.327671] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[39623.327672] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[39623.327674] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[39629.517308] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[40857.017339] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[40857.020416] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[40857.020419] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[40857.020420] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[40857.020421] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[40857.020422] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[40857.020423] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[40857.020424] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[40857.020426] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[40857.020426] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[40857.020427] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[40857.020428] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[40863.202610] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[42675.725653] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[42675.730941] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[42675.730950] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[42675.730953] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[42675.730958] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[42675.730962] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[42675.730965] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[42675.730969] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[42675.730973] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[42675.730977] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[42675.730980] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[42675.730983] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[42681.882049] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[48790.964543] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[48790.969970] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[48790.969979] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[48790.969981] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[48790.969987] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[48790.969990] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[48790.969993] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[48790.969998] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[48790.970002] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[48790.970005] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[48790.970008] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[48790.970012] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[48797.115666] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[49992.109259] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[49992.112338] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[49992.112343] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[49992.112345] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[49992.112348] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[49992.112350] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[49992.112352] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[49992.112354] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[49992.112357] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[49992.112359] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[49992.112360] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[49992.112362] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[49998.252749] wl0: link up (wlan0)
[58056.329286] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[58058.458398] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[58058.462256] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[58058.462262] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[58058.462264] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[58058.462268] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58058.462270] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58058.462272] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58058.462275] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58058.462278] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[58058.462281] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[58058.462283] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58058.462285] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[58067.324448] wl0: link down (wlan0)
[58067.324592] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[58067.327237] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[58067.327240] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[58067.327241] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[58067.327243] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58067.327244] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58067.327245] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58067.327247] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58067.327249] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[58067.327250] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[58067.327251] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[58067.327253] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[61120.860882] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
```

I am not sure how to fix this, what could be done to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it is happening after suspend/hibernate for most people? I haven't found a definite answer, but this might get you closer:

[What is the additional `phy0` or `PHY` in general?](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7773388.html)

Looks like it is probably something similar.

My wifi card stops working if I suspend and then resume, and I had to write a little script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` that removes the `wl` module and then reloads it. Hope this helps you in some way!

** EDIT **

Your system is reporting the card model as:

> [5.372637] wlan0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)

Apparently the 'wl' driver you are using is prone to these random errors. I have found someone else with the same Broadcom make that solved the problem by uninstalling the 'wl' driver and installing the one downloaded from Broadcom directly: (page is in French, translated to English)

https://translate.google.ca/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.hilpers.fr/1361762-machine-mi-figee-avec-driver&prev=search

Good luck, let me know if that works.

Comment: I set my laptop never to go to sleep or anything like that. Even just leaving it on it will just drop out in the middle of streaming of a video on YT or something. I try to avoid manually compiling drivers so that I don't make frakendebian but I just might need to give this a shot. I'll accept this answer and hopefully won't have to make a new question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Power management may be the issue. Have you tried the solution offered at the Wiki you reference in you question: `iwconfig wlan0 power off`?

Comment: I also have a realtek with that problem. Oh dear, those kind of bugs seem prevalent.

Comment: I tried this before posting. This didn't work for me either, I am not sure why.